# How do I nicely display relative time using VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, datetime

I want to display a "date/time submitted" value much the same way as Stack Overflow does

e.g.* 2 hours ago
    * 3 days ago
    * a month ago

I see extensive answers on how to do this in PHP but can someone help me with the VB version?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First calculate the exact time since submission:

```
Dim t As TimeSpan = DateTime.Now - submittedTime
```

Then you decide on what intervals you want to use for displaying the result. For example:

```
If t.TotalSeconds < 60 Then
   display = "Less than a minute ago"
ElseIf t.TotalMinutes < 60 Then
   display = t.Minutes.ToString() + " minutes ago"
ElseIf ...
   ... and so on
End If
```

Answer (score 4):

All the way back on question [11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11/how-do-i-calculate-relative-time/12), [Jeff posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11/how-do-i-calculate-relative-time/12#12) the code they use here on stackoverflow. It's in c#, but the conversion to vb.net should be pretty easy. There's heaps of other good suggestions in that question too.

Personally, I've used Sam Allen's code to get [prettydates](http://dotnetperls.com/pretty-date) before. He modeled it off some code that John Resig wrote, so it's good quality stuff. Once again, c#, but it [converts](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/) to vb.net pretty easily.

Answer (score 3):

You need a [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) structure

you simply substract [now] - [original message time] = difference time

you will need the [DateTime.Substract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.subtract.aspx) method

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is the TimeSpan structure.  This structure stores a span of time (as the name suggests).  It is the type returned when you subtract two DateTime structures

```
Dim start as DateTime = DateTime.Now 
...
' Some time after the start
Dim span = DateTime.Now - start
```

Answer (score 2):

I've posted a blog post to do just this. However it is in C#, but you can easily convert into vb.net
http://blog.nirandas.com/post/displaying-time-in-relative-format.aspx